# Is there a rule for Android 4+ to include VFP chip?

Tags: android, floating-point, google-play

I was filtering out devices which does not include VFP by not adding "ldpi + small" devices to manifest file. Even though it is not 100% correct, it was filtering out most of the devices as modern devices have better dpi.

However, now I saw that, for example Samsung Packet Neo supports Android 4+ but it has 160dpi (small + ldpi) and it has VFP chip. Now I want to support it. But I don't want other people to be able to install the app as it probably won't work on their devices. So I am curious about the rules/standards of Android OS versions and hardware used with them.

Is there a rule for an Android device to have a VFP chip if it can run Android 4+? So, can we say that a device supports VFP as It has Android 4+?

Comment: Just read `/proc/cpuinfo` and check whether `vfp` is in features. It's required since ARMv7 anyway.

Comment: @323go I already do it to prevent crash. I am trying to make it so they even can't download it to their devices. (As Google will show the application as "Not compatible with your device")

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Doesn't Google Play filter apps which which only contain ARMv7 binaries? Since ARMv7 indicates vpf, you should be home free on that?

Comment: @323go There are some popular ARMV5+ devices those actually include VFP. :/